# make bash accept function parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

so I have a bash script called myCMD which takes into its argument strings in the form of function()

however when I enter into the command line:

```
myCMD function()
```

it would complain `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

When I do `myCMD "function()"` though it will work

however I DON'T want to have to always wrap the argument in quotes everytime I use this command

Is there a way to configure the terminal/my script so that if you just enter `myCMD function()` it will treat `function()` as a string and will not complain accordingly even without quotes?

Comment: hmmm.  What do you want to do with it?

Comment: You could enter 'function' and then add the parens on later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash "function" is a reserved word, so be careful with that.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html

Why not change myCMD script to do what you want?

You could also wrap myCMD using the read command

```
#!/bin/bash 
read line 
myCMD "$line"
```

Usage requires invoking the wrapper then entering the string:

```
> myCMDWrapper
function()
myCMD was invoked with function()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `()` must be escaped some how as bash treats them specially otherwise.  Quotes will escape as well as `\(\)`.  Or you could rename `function()` to not have `()` in its name.

Answer (score 0):

Most shells not just bash treats `()` specially in the open so you have no choice but to quote it: `"()"`, `'()'`, `$'()'` or `\(\)`.